# Get Mailchimp list of unsubscribed users for the last month from API

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailing-list, list-unsubscribe

I want to receive the list of unsubscribed users from Mailchimp mailing list from Marketing API. I use this endpoint:

```
https://{{dc}}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{{list_id}}/activity
```

but it returns only the count of subscribed/unsubscribed users. I want also to retrieve email addresses of all unsubscribed users.

Endpoints with campaigns reports doesn't seems to retrieve such a data too.

Is this possible? Is there any other endpoint that can return my demands?
Also it would be helpful if the results will be trimmed by the date - in my case last month.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have figured it out. It was this endpoint:

```
https://{{dc}}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0//lists/{list_id}/members?status=unsubscribed&since_last_changed={{ISO_DATE}}
```